# Как динамически менять высоту итема листобокса в зависимости от контента в нем? auto не работает

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-phone-7

Есть листбокс. В нем отображается коллекция новостей. Каждая новость всегда имеет текстблок  с именем автора и картинку автора. Дальше, новость может иметь разный контент. Текст, картинку, текст с картинкой, текст с картинками  и тд. Для каждой такой новости у меня есть свой template и template selector' ом я выбираю как её отображать. Пример новости с картинкой:

```
<local:NewsTemplateSelector.Photo>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <Border BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="2"  Width="400" Height="300" Margin="10">
                                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Width="400" Height="300">
                                                <Image Source="{Binding SourceImage}" Height="75" Width="75" Margin="0,-225,0,0" />
                                                <Canvas Width="400">
                                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding SourceName}" Foreground="Black" FontSize="25" TextWrapping="Wrap" Height="55" Width="326" d:LayoutOverrides="VerticalAlignment, Height" />
                                                    <Image  Source="{Binding Photo[0].Big}" Height="250" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="326" Canvas.Top="69"/>
                                                </Canvas>
                                            </StackPanel>
                                        </Border>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </local:NewsTemplateSelector.Photo>
```

пример новости с текстом

```
 <local:NewsTemplateSelector.Texts>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Background="YellowGreen" Width="400" Height="300" >
                                        <Image Source="{Binding SourceImage}" Height="75" Width="75" Margin="0,-225,0,0" />
                                        <Canvas Width="400">
                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding SourceName}" FontSize="25" Foreground="Black" TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="326" Height="65" d:LayoutOverrides="VerticalAlignment, Height"  />
                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Texts}"  Foreground="Black" FontSize="25" TextWrapping="Wrap" Height="229" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="326" Canvas.Top="69" />
                                        </Canvas>
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </local:NewsTemplateSelector.Texts>
```

Тут все работает хорошо, выбирается как надо. Но вот например, если количество текста в новости с текстом много и он не вмещается в тексблок без скроллинга - я хочу растянуть этот текстблок до такого размера, чтобы текст полностью вмещался. А вместе с ним мне нужно будет растянуть и сам итем листбокса, чтобы тексбокс нормально отображался. Когда в  height я пишу auto - итем не отображается вообще(если провернуть такое с новостью с картинкой, где есть бордер красного цвета - то будет видно только красную полоску, а значит height итема листбокса = 0 или 1). Такая вот проблема.

Comment: Проблема в стекпанеле, вместо неё использую канвас, вроде помогает

Answer (score 0, accepted):

попробуй сделать новость с текстом немного по-другому: вместо Canvas используй Grid или еще один внутренний StackPanel. везде убери Height, на втором TextBlock выставь нужный Margin. Если не получится, отпишись, тогда я открою Visual Studio и все доделаю.

Comment: а, так ты разобрался)) ну тогда закрывай вопрос. а то я не заметил коммента

Comment: Да, просто использовал грид с колонками)